# How to filter JMeter listener sampes to full load

Tags: jmeter

I have some JMeter tests, that vary, among other parameters, the test load (number of users in a ThreadGroup).

The tests have listeners that write XML files that are, later, parsed by a Java processor that extracts the information.

I would like to filter the samples written by the listener to that samples performed when the tests were in full load (all threads active).

I can achieve this into the Java processor by filtering the samples using the `ng` attribute of each sample element.

My question is: does JMeter already have a built-in way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately JMeter doesn't provide this functionality, you can try using [Synthesis Report](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/) or [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/#Filter-Results-Tool) (both available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)) having "offset" property so you will be able to exclude ramp-up time.

The recommended way of installing JMeter Plugins and keeping them up-to-date is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)